# Cannot resolve module 'react-dom'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-dom, react-hot-loader

I've seen few posts related to this type of error. But couldn't resolve in mine.

My package.json:

```
"react": "~0.14.7",
"webpack": "^1.12.13",
"react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
.
.
```

I'm getting following error on webpack:

```
ERROR in ./public/src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-dom' in C:\Users\react-example\public\src 
@ ./public/src/main.js 19:16-36
```

But in the cmd line when I did

```
npm -v react-dom
```

I get 3.10.10. react-dom is there. But I wonder why it still gives this error.

When I installed react-dom through npm "npm install react-dom", and run webpack I get following errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMNullInputValuePropHook.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' C:\Users\react-example/node_modules/react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook in C:\Users\react-example\node_modules\react-dom\lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMNullInputValuePropHook.js 13:29-72

ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMUnknownPropertyHook.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' C:\Users\react-example/node_modules/react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook in C:\Users\react-example\node_modules\react-dom\lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMUnknownPropertyHook.js 15:29-72

ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMInvalidARIAHook.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' C:\Users\react-example/node_modules/react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook in C:\Users\react-example\node_modules\react-dom\lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMInvalidARIAHook.js 14:29-72

ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDebugTool.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' C:\Users\react-example/node_modules/react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook in C:\Users\react-example\node_modules\react-dom\lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDebugTool.js 16:29-72
```

Please help.

Comment: This solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47722556/15441

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Issue is `react-dom` is not installed, when you hit `npm -v react-dom`, it gives you the version of `npm` not `react-dom` version, you can check that by using `npm -v` or `npm -v react-dom` both will give you the same result. 
You are checking the package version incorrectly.

> How to install react and react-dom properly?

Use this to install react and react-dom:

```
npm install react react-dom --save
```

After that, you can check your `package.json` file, if react and react-dom has been installed correctly, you will find an entry for that.

> How to check install package version?

To check all the locally installed packages version:

```
npm list
```

For globally installed packages, use -g also:

```
npm list -g
```

To check the version of any specific package, specify the package name also:

```
npm list PackageName

For Example =>
   npm list react
   npm list react-router
```

After installation your `package.json` will look like this:

```
{
  "name": "***",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "***",
  "scripts": {
     ....
  },
  "repository": {
     ....
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    ....
    "react": "^15.4.2",          //react
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",      //react-dom
     ....
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     ....
  }
}
```

Latest version of `react-dom` is : 15.4.2

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom

Comment: I said in the question that after I install react-dom, I get those errors. Same is the case now.

Answer (score 31):

In my case I had an alias in my webpack.config.common.js:

```
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
    },
  },
```

I just removed this line:

```
'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
```

and it was fixed.

Comment: Or make sure @hot-loader/react-dom is installed.

Comment: so then you can't benefit from @hot-loader

Comment: This will happen more as folks switch to react-refresh.

Comment: I love you bro, I was searching and searching for solution.. it was so simple to fix, but so hard to find, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I used 'npm update' and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it was an alias I had in my webpack.conf, which was looking for `@hot-loader/react-dom`.

Answer (score 4):

For anybody reading this that wasn't able to figure it out. I had the same issue which I ended up resolving by installing the ["react-router" package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router) which is simply running the following command

`npm i react-router-dom --save` for a browser app.

`npm i react-router-native` for a native app.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update `react` and `react-dom`. Despite `react-dom` actually being installed, I was having this issue on `^15.5.4` and it went away with `^16.8.6`:

```
$ # update the react and react-dom modules
$ yarn add react react-dom
```

Ensure that the two version match exactly in `package.json`:

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
```

Delete `yarn.lock`, `node_modules`, and `yarn` again.

```
rm -Rf yarn.lock node_modules && yarn
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to solve this issue by updating your react react-dom module, try
`npm install react@latest react-dom@latest`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rm -rf node_modules && yarn` or `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` if you use npm instead of yarn.

Answer (score 0):

My particular issue for getting this error:

> ERROR in ./src/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'eact-dom' in
>   'C:\Users\Jose\Desktop\woz-u-React\React-Course\react-lesson-one\src' 
>   @ ./src/index.js 2:0-32  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js

To fix this issue, I had to unzip the folder before installing.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will resolve the problem.

npm install react react-dom --save

Answer (score 0):

For those using **Parcel**, this can occur if you are targeting `Node` for a browser-based app.

There are 3 ways Parcel will infer this from your `package.json`:

[image]

Remove node as the target, or specify the `--target` as `browser` at the command line.

Also see:

- https://v2.parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/
- https://v2.parceljs.org/configuration/package-json/

Answer (score -2):

Your app is pointing to the global version of react hence you need  install it manually using global keyword. You can also compare your  installed version of react-dom in package.json of your current project and globally installed react-dom version using command `npm -v react-dom` if both are different then manually install react dom using command:

```
sudo npm install -g react-dom@17.0.2
```