# while compiling my react project am facing the issue with module not found

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update my react project to an updated version and I am facing the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactDOM' in 'C:\Users\serole\Desktop\latest_react\app\node_modules\react-dom'
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 3:17-46
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080/ ./src/index
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
```

Comment: first remove /node_modules and package-lock.json and then try to install modules using npm install

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve module 'react-dom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574648/cannot-resolve-module-react-dom)

Comment: Please check below answer which will help you in details

Answer (score 0):

you can **remove** node modules and **install** like this

```
npm install react-dom@latest react@latest --save
```

try to install your **all package**  like this

it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

To install react-dom run the below command:

```
npm install react-dom --save
```

Now try checking the `package.json` for **react-dom**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.

Then try to install all modules using `npm install`.

And make sure in you `package.json` contains following modules,

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
```

Use this to install react and react-dom:

```
npm install react react-dom --save
```

Make sure that your **react** and **react-dom** packages have the same version to avoid incompatibility.

For more help to check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574648/cannot-resolve-module-react-dom).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: + react@16.8.6
+ react-dom@0.14.9,,,,the are installed

Comment: Yes because react and react-dom versions are different you have to make them same, you can do that by manually remove  react and  react-dom  and reinstall them via npm install react react-dom --save

Comment: actually we are using basic version of reactjs, so now am updating the react to latest version,,,as of now am facing lots errors here,,,,
again one more issue i found>>>>InternalPropTypes.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined
    at Object../node_modules/react-router/lib/InternalPropTypes.js

Comment: okay may be that is based on your code and version confirmability

Comment: you have to upgrade react-router as well, may be you can post . other issues in different question

Comment: Go through one by one and fix the issue , I hope now you are clear on  react and react-dom, and if yes then please accept answer

Comment: actually i want to develop my own site like blog..can you guid me

Comment: okay, will guide you, if this answer help u then please accept